# using QFtp rawcommand STOR to upload to server

Tags: c++, qt, ftp, qftp

```html
#include "client.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QFileInfo>
QString ConvertSize(qint64 size){
    QString output("0 Bytes");
    if(size<1024){
        output=QString::number(size)+" Bytes";
        return output;
    }else if(size>1024 && size <1048576){
        double newNumber=size/1024.0;
        output=QString::number(newNumber)+" KBs";
        return output;
    }else if(size >1048576){
        double newNumber=size/1048576.0;
        output=QString::number(newNumber)+" MBs";
        return output;
    }else if(size >1073741824){
        double newNumber=size/1073741824.0;
        output=QString::number(newNumber)+" GBs";
        return output;
    }else{
        return output;
    }
}
Client::Client(QObject *parent)
    : QObject{parent}
{
    qInfo()<<this<<"constructed on: "<<QThread::currentThread();
    connect(&ftp,&QFtp::commandStarted,this,&Client::commandStarted);
    connect(&ftp,&QFtp::commandFinished,this,&Client::commandFinished);
    connect(&ftp,&QFtp::dataTransferProgress,this,&Client::dataProgress);
    connect(&ftp,&QFtp::done,this,&Client::done);
    connect(&ftp,&QFtp::listInfo,this,&Client::listInfo);
    connect(&ftp,&QFtp::stateChanged,this,&Client::stateChanged);
    connect(&ftp,&QFtp::rawCommandReply,this,&Client::rawCommandReply);


}

Client::~Client()
{
    qInfo()<<this<<"deConstructed on: "<<QThread::currentThread();
}

void Client::connectToHost(QString ip, quint16 port)
{
    qInfo()<<"connecting to    "<<ip<<":"<<port;
    ftp.connectToHost(ip,port);
    qInfo()<<"loging in";
    ftp.login("testuser","123456");

}

void Client::commandStarted(int id)
{
    //qInfo()<<"command start:"<<id;
    quint8  command=ftp.currentCommand();
    switch (command){
    case 0:qInfo()<<"command start: "<<"None";break;
    case 1:qInfo()<<"command start: "<<"SetTransferMode";break;
    case 2:qInfo()<<"command start: "<<"SetProxy";break;
    case 3:qInfo()<<"command start: "<<"ConnectToHost";break;
    case 4:qInfo()<<"command start: "<<"Login";break;
    case 5:qInfo()<<"command start: "<<"Close";break;
    case 6:qInfo()<<"command start: "<<"List";break;
    case 7:qInfo()<<"command start: "<<"Cd";break;
    case 8:qInfo()<<"command start: "<<"Get";break;
    case 9:qInfo()<<"command start: "<<"Put";break;
    case 10:qInfo()<<"command start: "<<"Remove";break;
    case 11:qInfo()<<"command start: "<<"Mkdir";break;
    case 12:qInfo()<<"command start: "<<"Rmdir";break;
    case 13:qInfo()<<"command start: "<<"Rename";break;
    case 14:qInfo()<<"command start: "<<"RawCommand";break;

    }
}

void Client::commandFinished(int id)
{
    qInfo()<<"command finished: "<<id;
    if(ftp.error()){
        qInfo()<<ftp.errorString();
    }else{
        qInfo()<<"no error";
    }
    if(ftp.currentCommand()==9){
        myfile->flush();
        myfile->close();
        myfile->deleteLater();
        myfile=NULL;
        qInfo()<<"put command ended.closing open file.";

    }
}

void Client::rawCommandReply(int code, QString detail)
{


    qInfo()<<"reply code: "<<code<<"detail: "<<detail;
    if (code==226){
        qInfo()<<"transmission ended";
    }
    if (code==150){
        qInfo()<<"serverReady";
        dataChanel();
    }
    if(code==227){
        QString ip1=detail.split("(")[1];
        QString ip2=ip1.split(")")[0];
        qInfo()<<ip2;
        QStringList data=ip2.split(",");
        QStringList ip;
        QStringList ports;

        for (int i=0;i<data.size();i++){
            if(i<4){
                ip.append(data[i]);

            }else {
                ports.append(data[i]);
            }
        }
        qInfo()<<"ip:"<<ip.join(".");
        IpPorts.append(ip.join("."));
        qInfo()<<"port:"<<ports.join("-");
        for(int i=0;i<ports.size();i++){


            IpPorts.append(ports[i]);
        }

    }
}

void Client::dataProgress(quint64 now, quint64 all)
{
    qInfo()<<"now:\t"<<ConvertSize(now)<<"\t from:\t"<<ConvertSize(all);
}

void Client::done(bool error)
{
    if (error){
        qInfo()<<"error occured when done:"<<ftp.errorString();
    }
    //ftp.close();
    qInfo()<<"ftp connection closed";


}

void Client::listInfo(const QUrlInfo &i)
{
    qInfo()<<"dir found:"<<i.name();
}

void Client::stateChanged(int state)
{

    switch(state){
    case 0:qInfo()<<"state changed: "<<"Unconnected";break;
    case 1:qInfo()<<"state changed: "<<"HostLookup";break;
    case 2:qInfo()<<"state changed: "<<"Connecting";break;
    case 3:qInfo()<<"state changed: "<<"Connected";break;
    case 4:qInfo()<<"state changed: "<<"LoggedIn";break;
    case 5:qInfo()<<"state changed: "<<"Closing";break;
    }
}



void Client::abort()
{
    ftp.abort();
    qInfo()<<"ftp connection aborted";
}

void Client::ended()
{

    qInfo()<<"ftp connection ended";

}

void Client::upload(QString &location)
{
    myfile=new QFile(location);
    if(myfile->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
        ftp.rawCommand("PASV");
        ftp.rawCommand("TYPE I");
        QFileInfo fileinfo(myfile->fileName());
        qInfo()<<"size: "<<fileinfo.size();
        qInfo()<<"name: "<<fileinfo.fileName();
        qInfo()<<"uploading : "<<location;
        //qInfo()<<"file name is:"<<myfile->fileName();
        //ftp.put(myfile,fileinfo.fileName());
        QString text="STOR "+fileinfo.fileName();
        qInfo()<<text;
        ftp.rawCommand(text);
        //client.rawCommand("PASV");

        //client.rawCommand("TYPE I");
        //client.rawCommand("STAT");
        //client.rawCommand("STOR test.txt");
    }


}

void Client::list(QString &dir)
{
    qInfo()<<"listing dir:"<<dir;
    ftp.list(dir);
}

void Client::dataChanel()
{
    for(int i=0;i<IpPorts.size();i++){
        qInfo()<<IpPorts[i];
    }

    QTcpSocket* socket=new QTcpSocket(this);
    socket->connectToHost(IpPorts[0],IpPorts[1].toInt());
    QByteArray data;
    data=myfile->readAll();
    socket->waitForConnected();

    socket->write(data);
}
```

i need to upload files to a server and to make it resumeable i need to user raw commands and REST.

Im using QFtp raw command STOR and when it returns code 227 i parse the data and get the ip and open port then when i recieve code 150 i open a tcp port as a data socket to send the data but after a few seconds  it returns the error "Data channel timed out.\r\n Win32 error:   The network connection was aborted by the local system."
what am i doing wrong here?how am i supposed to use this command?

Comment: So did you check if your IP address decoding is correct? And is the IP address that the server is sending even correct? Does the address you decode match the one you connect to in `connectToHost`? You didn't show us what `IpPorts` is. So it's hard to tell if your decoding logic is correct. What is the port number you decode like? Show us the logging your code produces.

Comment: server returns "reply code:  227 detail:  "Entering Passive Mode (10,0,0,1,195,210)."and i then parse it to "10.0.0.1" "195" and cast port to int and then qtcpsocket socket;socket.connect to host(ip,port);socket.write(file);    ftp server is local .ipports is a qStringList which the first element is parsed ip and the rest are ports.

Comment: Then you parse it incorrectly. The port is `50130` (=`195<<8+210`).

Comment: oh!how could i miss that.i multiplied the first by 256 and added the second and connected the signal of tcpsocket but got the error "socket error : QAbstractSocket::ConnectionRefusedError".server is refusing a tcp connection.should i add anythin to socket.connecttohost(ip,port , sth else here)?

Comment: And is the 10.0.0.1 correct IP address? Can you post log file of any FTP client that can successfully transfer the file on the same machine, where your code fails?

Comment: qftp ftp;ftp.connecttohost();ftp.login();ftp.put(file,"name") works.its in the code ive posted but commented out.

Comment: is creating a new tcp socket and giving it the ip and port even the right approach?

Comment: Yes, that's the right approach. But you didn't answer any of my questions. Nor did you post your code logging yet.

Comment: what are the questions?i dont understand what you mean by code logging

Comment: *"And is the 10.0.0.1 correct IP address? Can you post log file of any FTP client that can successfully transfer the file on the same machine, where your code fails?"* + Your code outputs debug information to `qInfo()`. It would be useful to see that debug output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

so i was reading about it and somewhere said that using PASV isnt smart and instead use EPSV to open a port.i changed my code like this and parsed the new port and changed user permissions of local ftp server to all users and it worked!

```
myfile=new QFile(location);
    if(myfile->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
        ftp.setTransferMode(QFtp::TransferMode::Passive);
        ftp.rawCommand("TYPE I");
        ftp.rawCommand("EPSV");
        ftp.rawCommand("STAT");
        QFileInfo fileinfo(myfile->fileName());
        qInfo()<<"size: "<<fileinfo.size();
        qInfo()<<"name: "<<fileinfo.fileName();
        qInfo()<<"uploading : "<<location;
        qInfo()<<"file name is:"<<myfile->fileName();
        ftp.rawCommand("REST 1000");
        ftp.rawCommand("PWD");

        QString text="STOR "+fileinfo.fileName();
        qInfo()<<text;
        ftp.rawCommand(text);
```

Comment: The difference between `EPSV` and `PASV` is that `EPSV` support IPv6 (what I assume is not the issue here) and that `EPSV` does not carry the IP address and client should use the original IP address of the server for the data connection (that parts is not shown in your answer). I guess that this is what likely fixed the problem. The IP address `10.0.0.1` that the FTP server returns in `PASV` is probably not correct (that's why I asked about it).

Comment: If that's so, your original code was actually correct. And you didn't need to change to `EPSV`. Instead, you should fix your FTP server. Or workaround it by ignoring the IP address in the response and using the original FTP server IP address (what you are forced to do with `EPSV`).